# Find the Probability density function for the price of a ticket.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes, density-function

If I have the following scenario:

- The age $X$ of a person going to the cinema is normally distributed with a mean = $22$ and varianz = $5$
  going to a boxing match
- People under the age of 17 have to pay $10$ $
- From 17 to 18 they have to pay $12$ $
- And everyone above the age of 18 has to pay $15$ $

I want to calculate the PDF and mean for the price. My idea was to calculate the probability for a person within each of the three possible intervals. But I don't know how to and would appreciate any help regarding this problem!

Comment: The price can only take three values.  What's the probability someone pays $\$10$, say?

Comment: Look up a table for normal distribution.  Standard deviation $D= \sqrt{5}$, so under 17 means more than 5/D and 17 to 18 means between 4/D and 5/D deviations below the mean.

Comment: The "scenario" of a normal distribution of ages can only be approximately true.  After all the normal distribution allows no only fractional values and extremely large values, but also negative values.  Making sense of the normal distribution as an approximation is the bulk of your challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find probabilities under the normal curve for
intervals $(0,17).[17,18),[18,100).$

Because the specified normal distribution has
a bit of probability below $0,$ adjust the
above probabilities so that they sum to $1,$
to obtain the PDF.

Multiply PDF by ticket prices and sum to get
the expected value $\$14.05$of the distribution.

```
p = diff(pnorm(c(0,17,18, 100), 22, 5)); p
[1] 0.15864984 0.05320014 0.78814460
pdf = p/sum(pdf);  pdf
[1] 0.15865070 0.05320043 0.78814887
sum(pdf)
[1] 1
tkt = c(10,12,15)
mean = sum(tkt*pdf);  mean
[1] 14.04715
```

**Addendum** per comments showing how to use age distribution $A\sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=22,\sigma=4)$ to get probability of in interval $[17,18).$
$$P(17 \le A < 18) = P\left(\frac{17-22}{4} \le\frac{A-22}{4}<
\frac{18-22}{4}\right) \\
=P(-1.25 \le Z < -1) = 0.1587 - 0.1056 = 0.0531,$$
where the numbers at the end come from printed normal tables.
I don't know exactly the style of normal CDF table you may have, so I can't say exactly how to do it. But note that
$0.0531$ here is very close to $0.05320014$---about as close
as you're likely to get with printed normal tables.

Comment: Im sorry but I dont get the code you wrote. Can you explain?

Comment: Brief R tutorial: Vector `p` contains areas under the normal curve for the three intervals (because in R, `pnorm` is a normal CDF.) Dividing each element of `p` by `sum(p)` adjusts values in `p` slightly upwards so elements of `pdf` sum to $!.$  The three ticket prices are in vector `tkt`. These are multiplied elementwise by `*`, then summed to give mean value of the ticket price distribution. // Maybe use printed standard normal PDF tables to get elements of `p`. Then do the bits of remaining arithmetic on a calculator to get the answer. // See Addendum I made to my answer just now.